# Enumerate all CLR processes with their appdomains and their assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, process, .net-assembly, appdomain

I'm trying to enumerate all managed processes and list app domains they have and all assemblies inside them with help of `MdbgCore.dll` - managed wrapper of CLR debugging interfaces. Below code seems to work but it is not seeing most of the CLR programs - `EnumProcesses` simply returns single running program while I am sure there are more (launched by my for tests for example):

```
CorPublish corPublish = new CorPublish();

Func<int, int, List<CorAssembly>> EnumerateAssemblies = (pid, adid) => {
    MDbgEngine engine = new MDbgEngine();
    engine.Attach(pid);
    var result = engine.Processes.Active.Modules
            .Cast<MDbgModule>()
            .Select(m => m.CorModule.Assembly)
            .Where(a => a.AppDomain.Id == adid)
            .ToList();
    engine.Processes.Active.Detach().WaitOne();
    return result;
};
var result = corPublish.EnumProcesses()
    .Cast<CorPublishProcess>()
    .SelectMany(p => p.EnumAppDomains()
                      .Cast<CorPublishAppDomain>()
                      .Select(d => new
                        {
                            Process = p,
                            Domain = d
                        }))
    // I ommit my own program as debugger is already attached
    .Where(x => !x.Process.DisplayName.Contains("Console.vshost.exe"))
    .SelectMany(x => EnumerateAssemblies(x.Process.ProcessId, x.Domain.Id)
                        .Select(a => new
                        {
                            Process = x.Process,
                            Domain = x.Domain,
                            Assembly = a
                        }))
    .ToList();
```

Have anyone encountered such problems with this API? There is almost no documentation and examples out there.

*Note*: For curious, I just want to evaluate this API usability along with writing simple exemplary tool. I'm not going to use it in production code.

Comment: MdbgCore seems quite old. You may be interested in the CLR Memory Diagnostics project, aka [ClrMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) as well. A quick [sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx).